# simple monitor for xp systems

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring

I'm looking for a simple network monitor to run on users' PCs to track network disconnects. Specifically:

1. Be able to ping up to 5 hosts, either IP or name
2. Be able to log or redirect output to a file
3. Prefer to have a unique log file for each host being monitored!
4. Be able to select icmp ping or a wget-style connection to port 80 of a certain host that doesn't support ICMP replies.
5. Must be able to be run as the user, a Domain User, or via runas reliably.

I'm fine with a homemade script or freeware app, I just don't have time to write this myself and I need it like yesterday!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be too hard to write a simple C# app to do this and then add it in as a scheduled task.

Something like this would work. The try catch block is probably not ideal but it'd only be run once so it isn't too bad.

```
    try
    { 
        Ping p = new Ping(); 
        PingReply pReply = p.Send("ComputerName");
    }
    catch
    {
        //log time and date of fail
    }
```

I'm happy to try and knock something together if you like - could do with the C# experience!